# SAS to R conversion using SQLDF

Tags: r, sas, sas-macro

Appreciate if someone of you help me to convert below SAS code to R using SQLDF. I'm struggling to change the data type and apply sub string function in one single step.

Also In second step I'm not certain how to save the value of field in another new field which can be used in later stage.

```
 proc sql;
create table noodle as
select          MATRL_NBR,
             put(PLANT, z4.) as PLANT_NBR,
             PLANT_DESC,
             MFG_DT,
             input(substr(FISC_PD, 5, 4), best32.) as FISC_YR,
             input(substr(FISC_PD, 1, 3), best32.) as FISC_PD,
             input(substr(FISC_WK, 1, 3), best32.) as FISC_WK,
             PLANNED_ZNL,
             ACTUAL_ZNL,
             CRIT_SKU,
             IP_BRAND,
             IP_BU,
             CATG,
             MATRL_TYPE
from comb
;
quit;


proc sql noprint;
select          max(FISC_YR), max(FISC_WK)
into       :CURRENT_FISC_YR, :CURRENT_FISC_WK
from       noodle;
quit;
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried and explain how it did not do what you wanted.  Please explain your interpretation of what the SQL code you posted is doing.  There is not much need to attempt to mimic SAS's macro variables in R.  You can create actual variables instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following will achieve what you want:

```
library(sdldf)

noodle <- sqldf("select MATRL_NBR
              ,rightstr('0000'||cast(PLANT as varchar(4)),4) as PLANT_NBR 
              ,PLANT_DESC
              ,MFG_DT
              ,cast(substr(FISC_PD,5,4) as int) as FISC_YR
              ,cast(substr(FISC_PD,1,3) as int) as FISC_PD
              ,cast(substr(FISC_WK,1,3) as int) as FISC_WK
              ,PLANNED_ZNL
              ,ACTUAL_ZNL
              ,CRIT_SKU
              ,IP_BRAND
              ,IP_BU
              ,CATG
              ,MATRL_TYPE
      
      from comb")

CURRENT_FISC_YR <- max(noodle$FISC_YR)
CURRENT_FISC_WK <- max(noodle$FISC_WK)
```

You might want to use `as double` or `as float` instead of `as int` in the `cast()` functions depending on the numeric data type you require for FISC_YR, FISC_PD and FISC_WK.